# Can you run visual studio on a wacom cintiq companion?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wacom

As a painter and a learning programmer i was wondering if it would be possible to run visual studio on a Wacom Cintiq Companion? (the Windows 8 version not the Android) Just curious because I'm searching for a laptop to do both painting and programming and the full Windows 8 Cintiq sort of caught my eye. Thanks!

Comment: If it's Windows 8, there shouldn't be a reason why vs2012 wouldn't run on it.

Comment: It runs win8 on an Intel i7 from what I saw, so yes.

Comment: I kind of had a feeling it would, but I wasn't sure how well. I was wondering if anyone has tried it because It seems like i am the first to ask on the entire internet. But thanks for the reply! Appreciated!

Comment: Great! Thanks SnOrfus!